# Mac + Selenium2 + PhantomJS で PhantomJS が起動しない

Tags: macos, selenium, phantomjs

## 環境

- Mac OSX Yosemite (10.10.2)
- Selenium: 2.44.0
- PhantomJS: 2.0.0

## 症状

Mac で PHP のウェブアプリを、 PHPUnit を使ってエンドツーエンドのテストを書いています。

先週頃まで Selenium2 + PhantomJS がうまく起動していたのですが、最近になって起動しなくなってしまいました。

何か原因でしょうか？

Selenium2 と PhantomJS は brew でインストールしました。

```
$ brew info selenium-server-standalone
selenium-server-standalone: stable 2.44.0
http://seleniumhq.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/selenium-server-standalone/2.44.0 (4 files, 34M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/selenium-server-standalone.rb
==> Caveats
To have launchd start selenium-server-standalone at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/selenium-server-standalone/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load selenium-server-standalone now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.selenium-server-standalone.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    selenium-server -p 4444

$ brew info phantomjs
phantomjs: stable 2.0.0 (bottled), HEAD
http://www.phantomjs.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.0.0 (58 files, 50M) *
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/phantomjs.rb
```

下記ページにあるように `selenium-server -role hub` で Selenium Server を起動して `phantomjs –-webdriver=8000 –-webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4444` で PhantomJS を起動しています。

detro/ghostdriver
https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver

PhantomJS が正しく起動するといろいろなメッセージと `ok` が表示されるのですが、今は `Can't open '–-webdriver=8000'` と表示されます。

## 追記

これはまれになのですが、 `phantomjs --help` や `phantomjs --version` が実行できない場合があります。エラーメッセージが似ているので、これも同じような原因なのかなぁと想像をしています。このエラーメッセージの再現方法はわかりません。何かのタイミングでこのようになって、何かのタイミングでエラーが解消されます。

```
$ phantomjs –-help
Can't open '–-help'
$ phantomjs –-version
Can't open '–-version'
```

Comment: phantomjsとghostdriverのタグを追加しました。

Comment: ghostdriverのページには--webdriver=8080と書かれていますが、指定するポート番号が間違っているって事はないですよね？

Comment: タグ付けありがとうございます！付けていただいたタグを私も付けたかったのですが、私の信用度では新規のタグを付けれなかったため、助かりました :)

Comment: webdriver オプションは Web サーバーのポート番号のようです。質問のウェブサービスでは PHP のビルトインサーバーを利用していて、 `php -S localhost:8000` のように起動しています。また `–-webdriver=8080` として PhantomJS を起動してみましたが、結果は同じでした。 `$ phantomjs –-webdriver=8080 –-webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4444 Can't open '–-webdriver=8080'`

Comment: ポート番号を変えてもダメでしたか。残念…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

当方が Yosemite じゃないので確認できないのですが、 PhantomJS が 2.0.0 に上がったのはつい最近ですし、 Homebrew に PhantomJS 2.0.0 が入ったのが1週間前です。

- [History for Library/Formula/phantomjs.rb - Homebrew/homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/commits/efb005e32f913adc9b4b0d321f7af3b5c2810fef/Library/Formula/phantomjs.rb)

そして Yosemite だとソースからビルドできないという事例もまだ残っている（クローズされてない）ようです。

- [PhantomJS 2 does not build on OS X 10.0 (Yosemite) · Issue #12630 · ariya/phantomjs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12630)

Yosemite 向けのバイナリが

- [PhantomJS 2.0 binaries - Releases · eugene1g/phantomjs](https://github.com/eugene1g/phantomjs/releases)

に置いてありますので、こちらで試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます！試してみます！ > Yosemite 向けのバイナリ

Comment: Yosemite 向けバイナリをダウンロードして試してみましたが、同様のエラーになりました。また、ソースからビルドしたバイナリを使ってみましたが、やはり同じエラーになりました。

Comment: 1.9.8が Yosemite に対応してるのは確実なようなので、1.9.8 をビルドしてはいかがでしょうか。基本的には Qt 絡みのバグで1.9系も2.0系もトラブっててメンテが入っているようです。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます！1.9.8をビルドしてみます！

Comment: 1.9.8 をビルドして使ってみましたが、やはり同じエラーでした。 qt4 系と qt5 系を brew でインストールし直して、 selenium-server-standalone と phantomjs も brew でインストールし直したり、 phantomjs はビルドし直したりしてみましたが、同じエラーでした。 phantomjs の 1.9.7 は Yosemite はサポート対象外のようでビルドできませんでした。 `warning: "This version of Mac OS X is unsupported"`

Comment: 謎ですねぇ。逆に言えば、最初なぜ使えていたのかが謎ですね。[1.9.7はYosemite NG](http://phantomjs.org/release-1.9.html) 、とリリースノートに書いてあるのですが、[Yosemite(Mac OSX 10.10.1)でbrew installしたphantomJSがcrashしたときの対処法 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/shivaasee@github/items/534f84681aba5c366b8a) では「phantomjs@1.9.7-15 を入れると動く」とか。[grunt-spritesmith/grunt-spritesheet を使っていて PhantomJS が crash したら 1.9.7 にダウングレードするとなおる - @kyanny's blog](http://blog.kyanny.me/entry/2015/01/28/232732) でも1.9.7でOKで、インストールは「PhantomJSはnpmで入れろ」と。そちらの方向で試してみて下さい。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます！npm 試してみます！

Comment: npm でインストールした phantomjs を使ってみても、やはり同様のエラーでした。インストールしたバージョンは 1.9.8 だったので、 1.9.7 も試してみたいと思います。 `$ node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs --version
1.9.8`